# Launch URL in external chrome App when Flutter App Icon Clicked And Close Both Flutter and Chrome app on Back pressed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, native, url-launcher

**Hi Team,**

**I am creating an app in which when you open the flutter app it's launching the URL of the website in the chrome app. But when I pressed back from the chrome app I also need to kill the flutter app also.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    websitelaunch();
    super.initState();
  }

  bool x = false;

  void websitelaunch() async {
    const url = 'https://www.google.com';
    if (await canLaunchUrlString(url.toString())) {
      x = await launchUrlString(
        url,
        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Website launch from logo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my current main.dart file code and I used the package URL launcher plugin for the launch URL.**

```
url_launcher: ^6.1.4
```

[image]   [image]

**As you can see the app launches the google URL in chrome. But when the back button pressed the initial white screen of the flutter app it's still open.**

**Please help me how to kill the flutter app when we came back again to the flutter app.**

Answer (score 2):

Try this. for more details check the `url_launcher` package example [url_launcher_package example](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/example) and the [Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/)

```
  void websitelaunch() async {
     final Uri url = Uri(
              scheme: 'https', host: 'www.google.com', path:'');
              if (!await launchUrl(url,
                   mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
                   throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
  }
```

If you have website with headers (https://www.google.com/abc/def/) you have to added headers to the `path` as bellow,

```
void websitelaunch() async {
    final Uri url = Uri(
            scheme: 'https', host: 'www.google.com', path: '/abc/def/');
            if (!await launchUrl(url,
                mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
                throw 'Could not launch $url';
       }
  }
```

if you have backend response for the website you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72939917/component-name-for-www-xxxxxxxx-com-xxxxxxxx-is-null/72941508#72941508)