# component name for www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx/ is null

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

here is the code snippet that I trying to launch url,

```
onPressed: () async {
              final Uri url = Uri.parse(state.web);
               if ( await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                   aunchUrl(url);
               }else{
                  printLogs('cannot launch');
               }
          },
```

> state.web is https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/
>
> - this is comes from API,

and also I've tried below method as well,

```
onTap: () async {
    final Uri url = Uri(scheme: 'https', host: state.web, path:'');
           if (!await launchUrl(url,
              mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
                  throw 'Could not launch $url';
              }
 },
```

second method is working if there is only [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com), I need to add /xxxxxxx/ complete url. Is there any method to separate this /xxxxxxx/ part and get it separately ?

problem is above both methods are not working. requirement is open the url in browser/related application.

Comment: What's the error you get ?

Comment: There is no error. It doesn't open the browser. I want to open the url in browser or the particular application

Comment: component name for www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx/ is null

Comment: this was the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, split the url string,
after split it can get the url like an array,
like below,

```
[0]: "www.facebook.com" 
[1]: "xxxxxxx"
```

then we can use the below method to launch the url in browser.

```
onPressed: () async {
           final String source = https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/;
                  final splitedString = source.split('/');
    
                  final Uri url = Uri(
                    scheme: 'https',
                    host: splitedString[0],
                    path: '/${splitedString[1]}/');
                     if (!await launchUrl(url,
                          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
                          throw 'Could not launch $url';
                     }
             },
```